# How to convert a string ("€ 289,95") to a float ("289.95") in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

#### Context

I have Rails (4.0.1 + Ruby 2.0.0) connected to a PostgreSQL database filled with strings like "€ 289,95". The values have been scraped from a website using Nokogiri. I want to convert the strings to floating points.

#### What I've tried

Rails console:

```
listing = Listing.find(1)
=> #<Listing id: 1, title: #, subtitle: #, name: #, price: "€ 289,95", url: #, created_at: #, updated_at: #> 

listing_price = listing.price
=> "€ 289,95" 

listing_price_1 = listing_price.gsub(/,/, ".")
=> "€ 289.95"

listing_price_2 = listing_price_1.gsub(/€\s/, "")
=> "€ 289.95"

listing_price_3 = listing_price_2.to_f
=> 0.0
```

#### Problem

The code works in `irb` but doesn't work in the `rails console`.

#### What I want to know

How to convert a string `"€ 289,95"` to a float `"289.95"` in Rails?

Comment: `listing_price_1.gsub(/€\s/, "")` - leaves junk. The quickest, most dirty way to do this might be something like: `gsub(/,/, ".").gsub(/[^\d.]/, "").to_f` .. but it's really a dumbish non-locale aware approach to currency handling and will break on something as simple as `$1,200` (e.g. US).

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: Not an answer, but be aware there is a recent (11/22) exploit and hot fix for floating point parsing: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/11/22/heap-overflow-in-floating-point-parsing-cve-2013-4164/

Comment: Anyway, I suspect it doesn't work due to a Unicode/encoding issues .. but not sure where to look after that. My presented "solution" avoids this issue by not selecting on the € symbol directly.

Comment: @user2864740 I'm using Nokogiri to scrape the data. I might be able to not select the ```€``` with a regexp in Nokogiri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step where your technique is failing is when trying to strip away `€` and the space from `€ 289.95` with the regexp `/€\s/`, but this is not matching, leaving the string unchanged.

The space character in `€ 289,95` is probably a non-breaking space (U+00A0) rather than a “normal” space, and would be used in the web page so that the `€` and the value are not separated.

In Ruby the non-breaking space is *not* matched by `\s` in a regexp, so your call to `gsub` doesn’t replace anything:

```
2.0.0p353 :001 > s = "€\u00a0289.95"
 => "€ 289.95" 
2.0.0p353 :002 > s.gsub(/€\s/, "")
 => "€ 289.95"
```

Non-breaking space *is* matched by the [POSIX bracket expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) `[[:space:]]`, or by the [character property](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties) `\{Blank}`:

```
2.0.0p353 :003 > s.gsub /€[[:space:]]/, ""
 => "289.95" 
2.0.0p353 :004 > s.gsub /€\p{Blank}/, ""
 => "289.95"
```

So if you wanted a more specific regexp than in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20157083/214790) you could use one of these.

Comment: This is a great answer to a completely different question.

Comment: This was indeed the reason why my initial attempts did not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
"€ 289,95".sub(/\A\D+/, "").sub(",", ".").to_f
# => 289.95
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listing.price.delete('€ ') # => "289,95"
listing.price.delete('€ ').tr(',', '.') # => "289.95"
listing.price.delete('€ ').tr(',', '.').to_f # => 289.95
```

String's 'delete' method is good for removing all occurrences of the target strings.
and 'tr' method takes a string of characters to search for, and a string of characters used to replace them.

Answer (score 1):

Better probably than the accepted answer is:

```
"€ 289,95"[/[\d,.]+/].tr ',', '.'
```

Comment: Well, it will extract the first price-like expression and transform that. The others will choke on values like: '1 2'